# Creating a EntityFramework 5 Model with 500 tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-5

I am relatively new to EntityFramework and have been asked to explore the performance hit of using a Model with 500+ tables in it versus multiple models with the tables split up. I have read that using multiple models is prefered, but to test the performance and prove this concept I need to be able to create the huge model. I have tried to Update the .edmx file and have only been able to add ~275 tables. Does anyone know of a config setting that will allow the ability to add more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not recommended to use that many entities when using an .edmx file.  You will get much better performance using the Code First approach (even if you have an existing database, you can still use code first).

You will also want to pre-render your entity views if you have that many tables.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx

Comment: why is that "It's not recommended to use that many entities when using an .edmx file. You will get much better performance using the Code First approach"? CodeFirst is built on ObjectContext API and generates edmx on the fly from classes. How it can be faster than ObjectContext? True that view generation may take long time - but this is true for both approaches since view generation happens in ObjectContext.

Comment: @Pawel - many reasons.  The issue is not the in-memory model (which is not an edmx), it's the size of the xml file.  That XML file is serialized and deserialized into the designer, and large models make it very difficult to work with.

Comment: So this is not the performance per se but the design experience I can agree with that. Your response indicates that you are getting better runtime performance with CodeFirst which I don't think is true. Just to add to your response - to render views for CodeFirst you can use EF Power Tools or T4 templates from VS Gallery I wrote - http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/06/13/entity-framework-codefirst-view-generation-templates-on-visual-studio-code-gallery/